# (1NF - SQL )When to keep data separated by separator with example?

Tags: sql

Do you think the below tables meet the first normal form I'm confuse about (agency_timezone) and (stop_name) as I know I should Watch for data separated by separators but in these 2 cases specially first case should I keep column as it is ?

Table1:

(agency_id) |(agency_name)| (agency_url) |(agency_timezone)
m1234443  |transpor M12|htt://ed.fdfddddd|America/Montreal

Table2:

(stop_id)|(stop_code)|(stop_name)       |(stop_lat )
102831 |502131243|O'Brien/Dudemaine |45.528476

Comment: Are you sure america/montreal is a separated value?  timezone = america doesn't make much for sense as it'll cover 3 to 5 time zones pending what you call america...more if you include hawaii).  Neither does montreal for that matter (I guess Montreal in America would be eastern in this case?).  Are these actually separated values?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In the .txt file that they are provided to me they categorize it as you seen .I mention this as an example only . In fact I want to know the concept more precisely"when we should not split a column ?"  and I should not care about the data entry they done at this step .

Comment: It's best to split this whenever possible (sql does not handle array's in strings well).  Do you have agencies in multiple timezones then?  If you do...creating an agency_timezone table that holds the agency ID (foriegn key to agency table here) and the single time zone value (1 row per time zone, in this case 'america' as the first one and 'montreal' as the second one).  Your data looks really messy like this, is Obrien and dudemaine different names for the same stop then?